# How do you find out if a control is located on a tab control?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Hopefully this should be fairly easy, although after much searching I cant figure this out.

How do you find out if a control is located on a  tab?

```
If ctl.ControlType <> 'Tab Controls' Then
.....
End if
```

The reason for doing this is that I have a piece of code that runs through the controls on a form, but runs into a problem when cycling through controls on a tab.

```
 If ctl.Parent.CurrentView <> 2 Then
            MsgBox ctl.Name
 End If
```

The above causes the error:

```
Error: 348 Object doesnt support this property or method
```

Obviously it appears you cant refer to the current view of a tab control

Cheers for any advice any one has got out there

Noel

Comment: Why are you getting the form from the control's parent, instead of just checking the form? If you're looping a Controls collection, you know what object that collection is a member of, so you really shouldn't need to put in code to muck about with the control's parent object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what `ctl` is before using `CurrentView`:

```
Select Case ctl.ControlType
    Case acCheckBox
        ' do something for check box
    Case acTabCtl
        ' do something for tab control
End Select
```